# recover NTFS partition after running ntfsfix on the disk instead of the partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs

Originally my NTFS partition which occupies the whole external drive(1.8T) was having problems reading one file. It was probably corrupted, so I attempted to fix it by using `ntfsfix` on the partition. However, by accident, I run it on the device instead: `ntfsfix /dev/sda` , instead of `ntfsfix /dev/sda1`.

Now the system no longer detects the partitions, and if I try using `cfdisk`, it just interprets it as having multiple smaller partition, probably because it can't read the original one which was overwritten.

Is the partition recoverable at this point? Or at least a portion of the data? If so, how?